# stream logfile with nodejs to angular application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, stream

i'm looking for a way to continuously stream a logfile (live logstream) to an application built in angular. what would be the best way to go about that. i found 2 possible ways to do it. 
one uses nodejs module 'stream.io' but that looks like it would be a bit much for just some textfile streaming with all the 'on' events.. 
another way might be using a socket from the request and add a listener in the angular app like

`new EventSource('/showLog').addEventListener('message', handleCallback, false);`

where the handleCallback would add data to the $scope.log. 
The second option might be the simpler streaming option but i don't know how to push new log data into that socket. 
what would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use WebSockets or Server-Sent Events.

Comment: hm, not looked into websockets yet, you mean something like 'pusher' from angular and nodejs? that would work if nodejs is in control of when to push data to clients. but with logfiles, the files need to be in a 'tail -f' state where nodejs would constantly monitor log updates, detect it and then send data out. i know of no nodejs function to do that. any ideas there?

Comment: i've still had no luck getting this fixed. i get data to stream or pushed but putting a logfile in there with a 'tail -f' like construct still doesn't work.

Is there nobody who has a good idea of how to do this?